# bootstrap-table Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-table

i am new in this world, can anyone explain what is happening here?

I'm working on a asp.net razor application and i created this table witch has serverside pagination, serverside sort and search.

```
<div class="mx-n4 px-4 mx-lg-n6 px-lg-6 bg-white " id="users_table">
    <div class="table-responsive scrollbar mx-n1 px-1">
        <table class="fs--1 " 
        data-toggle="table"
        data-classes="table"
        data-searchable="true"
        data-search="true"
        data-sortable="true"
        data-sort-reset-page="true"
        data-url="/Client/Index?handler=Users"
        data-side-pagination="server" 
        data-pagination="true"
        data-total-not-filtered-field="totalNotFiltered">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class=" align-middle col-2" scope="col" data-sortable="true" data-formatter="window.usersTableRenderField" data-field="fullName">@Localizer["Client_Name"]</th>
                    <th class=" align-middle col-4" scope="col" data-formatter="window.usersTableRenderField" data-field="subscriptions">@Localizer["Client_Subscription"]</th>
                    <th class=" align-middle col-1" scope="col" data-formatter="window.usersTableRenderField" data-events="window.usersTableEvents" data-field="actions"></th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="list" id="facility-table-body">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything work just fine but i get this console error when table is created (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create'))
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5i5v.png)

i do not understand what ecommerce-dashboard js has to do with my table. Also in the network the initiator says that it is echarts-utilis js.

I really do not understand what is happening.